# Problema teclado se cierra automaticamente al seleccionar un TextFormField en flutter

Tags: flutter

No sé que pasa que al seleccionar un campo de texto (Textformfield), se cierra automaticamente el teclado, todo el tiempo, aqui dejo el codigo de la pagina que sucede, porque en otras paginas no pasa.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AddProducto extends StatefulWidget {
  final String user,id_ticket;
  const AddProducto({super.key,required this.user,required this.id_ticket});


  @override
  State<AddProducto> createState() => _AddProductoState();
}

class _AddProductoState extends State<AddProducto> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _data = []; 
  String? _selectedItem = null; 
  bool _mostrarerror = false;
  bool _isselectedItemClasi=false;
  bool isChecked = false;
  TextEditingController stockCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cuerpoCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController cantidadCtrl = new TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); // Clave para identificar el formulario
  
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    llenarCombo();
    stockCtrl.text = 0.toString();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        title: Text('Agregar producto',style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            color: Colors.white, 
            fontSize: 30,
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
        ),)
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            height: screenSize.height,
            width: screenSize.width,
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Text('Producto',style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 124, 124, 124)),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(  
                    hint: Text('Productos'),
                    value: _selectedItem,          
                    items: _data.map((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item['id_producto'].toString(),
                        child: Text(item['clasi']+' '+item['nombre_producto']+' '+item['descripcion_producto']),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isselectedItemClasi=true;
                        _mostrarerror=false;
                        _selectedItem = newValue!.toString();
                        for (var item in _data) {
                        if (item['id_producto'].toString() == _selectedItem) {
                          // Actualiza el valor de stock
                          stockCtrl.text = item['cantidad'].toString(); // Actualiza el TextFormField de stock
                          break;
                        }}
                      });
                    },
                    
                                  ),
                  ),
                Visibility(visible: _mostrarerror,child: Text('Por favor, seleccionar un local',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 22, 9)),)),
                Container(
                  width: screenSize.width/5,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Colors.red,
                    readOnly: true,
                    controller: stockCtrl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Stock',
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Por favor, ingresa la observacion';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: screenSize.width/2.5,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: cantidadCtrl,
            
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Cantidad',
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Por favor, ingresa la cantidad';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      // Permite solo números
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: cuerpoCtrl,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Observacion',
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Por favor, ingresa la Observacion';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Checkbox(
                      value: isChecked,
                      onChanged: (bool? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isChecked = !isChecked; // Actualiza el estado del checkbox
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    Text('Enviar correo'),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: ElevatedButton(      
                    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green)),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if(!_isselectedItemClasi){
                         setState(() {
                            _mostrarerror=true;
                         });
                      }else{
                        String checkbox ='';
                        if(isChecked){
                          checkbox='1';
                        }else{
                          checkbox='0';
                        }
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState!.save();
                          // Aquí puedes procesar los datos del formulario (name y email)
                          var respuesta = await agregarProducto(widget.user,_selectedItem,widget.id_ticket, cuerpoCtrl.text,cantidadCtrl.text,checkbox);
                          if(respuesta){
                            Navigator.pop(context,true);
                              mostrarSnackbar('Producto agregado');
                              
                          }else{
                            mostrarSnackbar('Falló agregar producto');
                            Navigator.pop(context,false);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text('Crear'),
                  ),
                ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  void mostrarSnackbar(String mensaje) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        content: Text(mensaje),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

en un momento pense que podia ser **resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,** pero lo puse en true, y ni aun asi.
hay otra pagina que tambien me pasa lo mismo
aqui:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class AddVisita extends StatefulWidget {
 final String user,id_ticket;
 const AddVisita({super.key,required this.user,required this.id_ticket});
 
 @override
 State<AddVisita> createState() => _AddVisitaState();
}

class _AddVisitaState extends State<AddVisita> {
 
 DateTime? selectedDate; // Variable para almacenar la fecha seleccionada
 String cuerpoCtrl = '';
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   selectedDate = DateTime.now();
 }

 Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
   final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
     context: context,
     initialDate: DateTime.now(),
     firstDate:  DateTime.now(),
     lastDate: DateTime.utc(2040, 12, 31),
   );
   if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
     setState(() {
       selectedDate = picked;
     });
   }
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   
   return WillPopScope(
     onWillPop: () async {
       // Personaliza la respuesta al botón "atrás" del sistema
       Navigator.pop(context, false);
       return false; // No permite que Flutter maneje el botón "atrás" por defecto
     },
     child: Scaffold(
         resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
         appBar: AppBar(
           backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
           title: Text(
             'Editar Visita',
             style: TextStyle(
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               color: Colors.white,
               fontSize: 30,
               fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
             ),
           ),
         ),
         body: ListView(
           children: [
             Container(
               height: screenSize.height,
               width: screenSize.width,
               child: Padding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                 child: Column(
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                   children: [
                     Container(
                       child: Text('Fecha',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                     ),
                     InkWell(
                       // Utiliza InkWell para hacer clic en la fecha y mostrar el DatePicker
                       onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
                       child: Container(
                         width: double.infinity,
                         height: 60,
                         alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           border: Border.all(),
                         ),
                         child: Text(
                           "${selectedDate?.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0],
                           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     Container(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15,bottom: 15),
                       child: Form(
                         key: _formKey,
                         child: TextFormField(
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                             labelText: 'Observacion',
                           ),
                           validator: (value) {
                             if (value!.isEmpty) {
                               return 'Por favor, ingresa la Observacion';
                             }
                             return null;
                           },
                           onSaved: (newValue) {
                             cuerpoCtrl = newValue.toString();
                           },
                         ),
                       )
                     ),
                     Center(
                       child: Container(
                         width: screenSize.width / 1.3,
                         height: 60,
                         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, right: 15, bottom: 15),
                         child: ElevatedButton(
                           style: ButtonStyle( backgroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green)),
                           onPressed: () async {
                             String year = selectedDate!.toLocal().toString().split(' ')[0].split('-')[0];
                             String month = selectedDate!.toLocal().toString().split(' ')[0].split('-')[1];
                             String day = selectedDate!.toLocal().toString().split(' ')[0].split('-')[2];
                             String fecha_i=year+month+day;
                             if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                               _formKey.currentState!.save();
                               int respuesta = await crearVisita(widget.user,widget.id_ticket,fecha_i,cuerpoCtrl);
                               if( respuesta==1){
                                 mostrarSnackbar('Visita creada.'); 
                                 Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                               }else if(respuesta==0){
                                 mostrarSnackbar('Hay visitas en proceso aún.'); 
                               }else{
                                 mostrarSnackbar('Error al cerrar(query).'); 
                               }
                             }
                             
                           },
                           child: Text('Guardar'),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
         )),
   );
 }

 void mostrarSnackbar(String mensaje) {
   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
     SnackBar(
       duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
       content: Text(mensaje),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

No se que puede ser, no hay mucha informacion al respecto...
Ojala alguien pudiera ayudarme porfavor.

Nota: Borré los http por seguridad en la empresa donde trabajo, pero fucionan bien.

Comment: Te pasa en el emulador o dispositivo fisico?

Comment: @Nagash me pasa en el dispositivo fisico

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en tu _formKey, cambia final por static.
static GlobalKey _formKey = GlobalKey();
// Clave para identificar el formulario